# How to get count of number of rows in table that have multiple matching row values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have a LoginHistory table in SQL .
I want to execute a command that will return the count of logins on a certain date.
But if a user has logged in multiple times I only want to record it as one log in.

So I can see how many logged in on one day and not how many times they logged in on that day.

So far I have this ....

```
   select count(username) as TotalUserCountOnTheDay
   from dbo.LoginHistory
   where datediff(day,LoginDate, '2014-11-19') = 0
```

But this returns the number of log-in's or all user.
The result is 15 rows, it should be 4

The table I'm querying:
[image: LoginHistory_Table]

Comment: interesting `count()` without `group by` and you still get more than one row ?

Comment: Yup, the above displays column "TotalUserCountOnTheDay" value 15.

Comment: Please use group by "username"

Comment: just add a group by clause at the end as `group by username` and make sure that `username` is in the select list.

Comment: Adding the group by in the above example returns four rows each with the value equal to the number of times a user has logged in. While the number of rows in this query would answer my question of "how many users logged in on this day", ideally I just want one row with one value. (in this case, 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count *distinct* users:

```
select count(distinct username) as TotalUserCountOnTheDay
from dbo.LoginHistory
where datediff(day,LoginDate, '2014-11-19') = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the *distinct* keyword could help you in this case.

Comment: can you provide syntax ?

Comment: Thorsten Kettner just did that

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one

```
select count(username) as TotalUserCountOnTheDay
   from dbo.LoginHistory
   where datediff(day,LoginDate, '2014-11-19') = 0
   GROUP BY username;
```

OR

```
select count(distinct username) as TotalUserCountOnTheDay
   from dbo.LoginHistory
   where datediff(day,LoginDate, '2014-11-19') = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` . Ex.

```
SELECT COUNT(l.username) AS TotalUserCountOnTheDay
FROM dbo.LoginHistory  AS l
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, l.LoginDate, '2014-11-19') = 0
GROUP BY l.username
```

Or

```
 SELECT COUNT(l.username) AS TotalUserCountOnTheDay
    FROM dbo.LoginHistory  AS l
    WHERE l.LoginDate = '2014-11-19'
    GROUP BY l.username
```

It should return the count of each username login for selected date.